# Is there ways to trigger user-defined route after onCompletion of a consumer

Tags: apache-camel

From observation, a route in camel is performing

1. **Consumer action** [exclude onCompletion part] (The definition in from endpoint)
2. **User-defined route after from endpoint** (if any exchange generate from step 1)
3. **onCompletion part of the consumer** (after the core thread return from user-defined route)

example

```java
    from()                       // step 1
        .log("some log")         // step 2
                                 // step 3
```

---

### My Question

Is Camel have any ways to perform

1. **Consumer action** [exclude onCompletion part] (The definition in from endpoint)
2. **User-defined route (logic 1)** (if any exchange generate from step 1)
3. **onCompletion part of the consumer** (after the core thread return from user-defined route)
4. **User-defined route (logic 2)** (trigger if the onCompletion part is succeed)

Comment: Hi! Looking at the manual, there appears to be just what you're looking for described here: https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/oncompletion.html. Does this not do what you need?

Comment: @Screwtape yes, this is what I am looking for. I overlook this page. thanks anyway.